# why is assert_not_called on session.commit() and session.flush() calls not registering?

Tags: python, session, mocking

I have the following function:

```
#in exchanges.exchange.py
def check_currency(): 
    with session_scope_retries() as db_session:
        ....
        db_session.flush()
        db_session.commit()
```

Then my test function:

```
def test_bad_currency_data_not_persisted(mock_check_currency, metadata_dict):
    ...
    with patch('exchanges.exchange.session_scope_retries') as db_session:
        check_currency(security_files_generated)
        db_session.flush.assert_not_called()
        db_session.commit.assert_not_called()
```

The above test passes?

When I set a breakpoint inside the `session` in my function, I can see it registering `db_session.flush()` and `db.session.commit()`, so shouldn't my test case fail?

Expected test case to fail since `commit` and `flush` are called.

Comment: Where does the `session_scope_retries` come from? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example